# How to set text color of aspx tree node in run time

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress

I want to write something like this on the c# side:

```
protected void eventHandler(object sender, DevExpress.Web.SomethingTreeViewEvent e){

  //figure out color mapping, may depend on date and time, whatever.

  foreach (node in in mytree)
     node.textColor = colorMapping(mappingFunc(node));
}
```

Question is,
what is the method for setting the color?
There is `TreeViewNodeTextStyle`, but is is read only, and it's constructor takes no arguments.

Comment: use TreeNodeDataBoundEvent https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.treeview.treenodedatabound.aspx and use `e.Node.Style.Add("color", "blue");`

Comment: are you mentioning DevExpress TreeList?https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/CustomDocument4011

Comment: Oh, I should have mention that I'm working with the DevExpress framework. Can explain why the intelisence can't recognize the TreeNodeDataBoundEvent.